# MySQL Script for find finding missing entry from a specific group and then enter the missing row on that group

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, database-administration

I have one table **ClockIn** which is as follows:

| Id | TimeStamp | WorkDayId | EmployeeId | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-19 08:00:00 | 148 | 1 | Start |
| 2 | 2021-10-19 10:00:00 | 148 | 1 | End |
| 3 | 2021-10-19 11:00:00 | 148 | 1 | Start |
| 4 | 2021-10-19 08:00:00 | 149 | 2 | Start |
| 5 | 2021-10-19 17:00:00 | 149 | 2 | End |

The table is basically using for attendance of the employee. I need to write one SQL script which will find the employee who has any **start** but forgot to enter **end** time (*Means he has no rows for Type=end, but has start. NB: One employee might have multiple Start and End in the same day*).

First I need to figure out that employee and then I have to enter the missing End row for that employee. And the End TimeSpan will be **StartTime + 8hrs**.

I am using MySql DB, so I am trying to write a MySql script. Do I need to use any temporary table or procedure for this. I am totally stuck how to do that. Any help would be appreciate please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `NOT EXISTS` another record for same employee, same day, "End" timestamp is after the timestamp for "Start"

```
SELECT a.*
FROM ClockIn a
WHERE a.Type = 'Start'
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM ClockIn b
  WHERE b.EmployeeId = a.EmployeeId
  AND a.WorkDayId = b.WorkDayId
  AND a.Timestamp < b.Timestamp
  AND b.Type = 'End'
);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf83dfce56500b12cc945848e94e8b9a

Examples in the above link also includes an `INSERT` statement for create the "End" record, but it is a question if it always add 8 hours from "Start".

Comment: Massive use of NOT EXISTS ;)